# Возможно ли в xNet отследить прогресс скачивания файла C#

Tags: c#, download, xnet

Собственно вопрос уже задал. Вот код для самой скачки.

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    HttpResponse response = request.Get(link);
    response.ToFile("file");
}
```

Но как вывести прогресс на ProgressBar?

Comment: А можно вопрос? Почему xNet? Это же не библиотека, а сборник велосипедов - практически всё реализовано самим `.Net` и сделано гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Ну там вроде есть событие `DownloadProgressChanged` - стоит на него подписаться и всё.
Типа

```
 request.DownloadProgressChanged += (value) => {progressBar1.Value = value;}
```

Comment: Если я хочу повесить метод, то как это сделать?
Что-то типа: `request.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressBar();`? Но как мне в методе узнавать состояние скачки из `DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e`?

Comment: Если речь идет про этот `xNet` https://github.com/X-rus/xNet то `OnDownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressBar`, где `DownloadProgressBar(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {/*Обработчик*/}. Главное чтоб сигнатура с делегатом ивента совпадала.